Using a render prop affecting state changes inside component
I'm currently using a component from a UI library to render a drawer, it has a render prop that allows me to control the closing of the drawer. However, when I try use the render prop other state variables that are being set inside the component are no longer working, when I don't use the render prop the state variables are working as expected.
A small example:
const [count, updateCount] = useState<number>(0);

<Drawer>
   {({ close }) => {
      <Button onClick={() => close()}>Close</Button>
      <Button onClick={() => updateCount(1)>Test</Button>
   })
</Drawer>

In this example clicking the second button will not update the state as expected.
const [count, updateCount] = useState<number>(0);

<Drawer>
   <Button onClick={() => close()}>Close</Button>
   <Button onClick={() => updateCount(1)>Test</Button>
</Drawer>

In this example the second button would update the state as expected.
Does the use of the render prop change the behaviour of the component? Am I missing something here? Is there a way I can get the standard state setter to work as expected while using the render prop?

Could you provide a reproducible example? I was unable to reproduce the situation you described the state not getting updated in this Stackblitz
